# How to join two tables using Guava

Tags: java, join, guava

Fact table :

```
Id Year Month countryId Sales
1  1999 1     1         3000
2  1999 2     1         2300
3  2000 3     2         3999
4  2000 4     3         2939
```

Dimension table:

```
Id country province
1  US      LA
2  US      CA
3  US      GA
4  EN      LN
```

and I use Guava table like this :

```
Table<Integer, String, Object> table = Tables.newCustomTable(
        Maps.<Integer, Map<String, Object>> newLinkedHashMap(),
        new Supplier<Map<String, Object>>() {
            public Map<String, Object> get() {
                return Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
            }
        });

    table.put(1, "Year", 1999);
    table.put(1, "Month", 1);
    table.put(1, "countyId", 1);
    table.put(1, "Sales", 3000);
    // ...... etc


    table1.put(1, "county", "US");
    table1.put(1, "provice", 1999);
    // ......
```

I want to implement a `LEFT JOIN` like:

```
1 1999 1 1 3000 US LA
2 1999 2 1 2300 US LA
3 2000 3 2 3999 US CA
4 2000 4 3 2939 EN LN
```

What should I do?

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Is it a database? Is it possible to do the join in the query?

Comment: `table1.putAll(table2);` ?

Comment: Maybe some diff datasource one from MySQL and the other from Excel - -

Comment: table1.putAll(table2);  I was thy this , but is not work out......

Answer (score 3):

Guava's `Table` isn't supposed to be used like any SQL's table, as it is a collection. SQL's tables are designed to be indexable, sortable, filterable, etc. Guava's `Table` has only a fraction of those and only indirectly, and joints aren't part of them (unless you play with transformations).

What you need to do is to have your two tables and loop through the elements of `table` and find the corresponding mapping in `table1`.

In your case, I believe you're better off with a `List` replacing `table` and a Guava `Table` for `table1`. Loop through the list and make your final objects as you get your elements.

Comment: +1 Agree. `Table` in Guava is designed to describe data structure such as `Map<FirstName, Map<LastName, Person>>`.